# Brownie Causes Dropped Transactions That Still Go Through

Tags: solidity, rinkeby, brownie

While running my test programs in Brownie, it seems like half the time the transactions are dropped and the script halts. When looking up the transaction hash afterward, the transactions have processed. This is on the Rinkeby testnet.

1. What is going on?
2. Is there anyway to increase the threshold in brownie to wait longer for these transactions?